# Magento 2 - Can not add grouped product child to cart

Tags: magento2, product, cart, grouped-products, out-of-stock

In Magento 2, I have a grouped product with 3 childs.

`Child 1` and `Child 2` are out of stock.

`Child 3` is in stock.

When I try to add `Child 3` into cart, there is an error about the two other product that are out of stock.

Result : it's impossible to add a grouped product child to cart if other childs are out of stock.

Do you know why and how to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer.

I'm having the same issue and I'm posting my specs here:

I'm using Magento 2.3.3 on PHP 7.1

One custom premium theme with it's included extensions and settings and data migrated from Magento 1.9.3.1

I'm showing out of stock products on category page as I don't want to hide them if they are not in stock.